# Kendo Chart Export to JPG or PNG

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have been researching this topic for awhile now. I know there are other questions relating this topic but a lot of the answers I haven't gotten to work or lead to 404 Not Found Webpages like this one http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/dataviz/chart/kendo-ui-chart-export.aspx. Does anyone have a current way to export a Kendo Chart to JPG or PNG? I have tried looking to Inkscape but I am not familiar with it at all.

Comment: Try the following URL http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendo-ui-chart-export in order to solve broken link

Comment: I downloaded a library that converts svg instructions to bmp. With this I can include the rendered image in my pdf. I have all these things encapsulated and called when the are needed . For Example -->Draw Scatter-->Convert Scatter to BMP--> Include bitmap in a PDF Doc for viewing and printing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the nuGet library svg and posting a tidbit that might be useful for you. You can obtain the svgFileContents from and chart.

```
public BitMap RenderReportFromSVG(string svgFileContents)
{
     System.Drawing.Bitmap _bitmap=null;
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(svgFileContents);
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
     {
          XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
          xdoc.LoadXml(svgFileContents);
          var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(xdoc);
          _bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();                
     }
     return _bitmap;
 }
```